# SCM-Activity-Plugin and Taglist in SONAR

Tags: maven, sonarqube, taglist

I'm currently trying to setup a little CI environment for our java maven project. I'm using Eclipse. Jenkins and Sonar. So far most parts seem to work, except the scm-activity-plugin and taglist plugin in sonar. I installed the plugin, restarted sonar and the pluging shows up under the configuration. But I don't see any user information in the source view... I specified the scm subversion connection (url/password/user) under project->settings -> SCM Activity in Sonar, but still no luck. Do I need to specify the scm connection in the maven pom (where do I need to put it in a multimodule setup)? Same goes with the Taglist Plugin? Installed, configured in the checkstyle comment segment but no results are visible?!

So, the question is, what in information must be set in the POM? Till now I don't specify scm or sonar in the pom an trigger the sonar integration via jenkins...what is the best practice here? Do I need to specify things like sonar, scm, jenkins, artifactory in the pom?

Thanks,
Ingo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the SCM Activity plugin since you use Maven you need to specify the SCM Url in your pom.xml like this :

```
  <scm>
    <url>scm:svn:svn://255.255.255.255/path/to/your/project</url>
  </scm>
```

For more details about url format see : http://maven.apache.org/scm/scm-url-format.html 
Taglist plugin doesn't need any configuration in your pom.xml but you need to create rules to define the tags you want to hunt. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Taglist+Plugin

Comment: Hmm. Still no success. I'm using TRAC with its subversion integration. I don't want to use the complete scm integration with maven (developerConnection etc) since I do this stuff via Jenkins...thus, I tried the following: <scm><url>http://<ip>/trac/<repo>/browser/src/<project></url></scm> I this correct? Do I need to install an svn client on the server (I just tried SilkSvn)...Thanks

Comment: Okay, now it works. I added the complete scm tag and added the server authorization in the maven settings... Thanks